# Library that 'connects' with Google calendar, Outlook calendar and iCalendar

Tags: javascript, php, google-calendar-api, icalendar, outlook-restapi

We have a system that schedules 'meetings' and we want to integrate a sync button that would pretty much take the meeting data(time and hour) and sync it with one of the three calendars (Google, Outlook or iCalendar)

I was curious if there is any library(js or php) that eases this syncing so I don't have to go and create a syncronization for all 3 APIs.

Thank you!

Comment: Does your system produce a .ics feed ?  If so people can subscribe to the calendar of meetings.  I think that what you want is a 'subscription' not a 'sync'.  Sync implies a 2-way update ie having someone making an updated in google, or outlook or icalender  and that update being reflected back in your system.  If no .ics feed, there are various "php icalender"s out there that you can perhaps use (Search) Please note that stack is not really about 'curiosity', it is intended as a focused Q&A, research expected. https://stackoverflow.com/tour & https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask